# integrating external application exe file in java

Tags: java, .net, architecture

I have two external application exe files(written in .Net Language) which I need to integrate inside my java application. I understand that I can integrate and run exe's in my local system through process java api. But when I deploy my java app through weblogic how it will execute/call windows exe files? please suggest.

Comment: What problem do you anticipate? Did you try doing it? I am assuming though that the .net exe files are indeed on the same machine as where you deploy your java code to.

Comment: my java application ear deploys on Linux. how can we communicate from java program inside web application ear to external software files (exe's)

Comment: Obviously you cannot do that. You need to use remoting. Use something like HTTP server on windows, RPC etc.